# I am trying to record a macro which tries to import data from a text file and paste it to a particular cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2010, vba

I have nearly 30 .txt files which needs to be automatically imported into a corresponding cell of a excel. So i came up with recording a Macro by importing text from data tab.

Data to be imported to Excel:

`Sample.txt`:

```
123-345-678-91-0
```

But if data to be imported to Excel:

`Sample1.txt`:

```
123-345-678-910
345-678-819-000
```

Everything works fine when Sample.txt is returning one row of output as shown above but if more than one row is returned as shown in Sample1.txt and I record a macro it will **paste the corresponding rows of data in two successive rows instead of one cell.** You can find about the issue in the below image.

**Approaches tried:**

1. Tried pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> before importing data from text.
2. Tried pressing double click on the corresponding cell before importing from text.
   3.Tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> before importing.

PFB image for the same.

[image: Img]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this manually would be to:

- Open the text file in notepad
- Select the entire file
- Open Excel
- Select the cell desired
- Put the cursor into the formula bar
- `Paste`

You could record a macro to do some of the above (the part that is in Excel).

Perhaps a more efficient method would be, without recording a macro:

*Since your example shows only single lines that do not need to be split into separate columns, I did not take that into account.*

- Get the file path
- Read the text into a variant array, splitting it on the `NewLine` character (usually CHAR(13))
- `Join` that split text into an array, using CHAR(10) as the delimiter (vbLF) which is what Excel uses to put stuff on new lines in a single cell.
- Write that to the cell desired.
- Adjust column width and heights to fit.

Here is one way of doing this.  It requires setting a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` so as to be able to use the `FileSystemObject`.  The FileSystemObject is described in the MSDN Library starting at [VBA Reference for FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706(v=vs.60).aspx) object:

```
Option Explicit
'Set Refereence to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub ImportTextFileToOneCell()
    Dim vFileName As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim V As Variant

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set R = WS.Cells(1, 1)

vFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
If vFileName = False Then Exit Sub

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(vFileName, ForReading)

V = Split(TS.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
V = Join(V, vbLf)

R = V
With R
    .ColumnWidth = 255
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: can you modify the part of the code to include the filepath and writing it to a particular cell.

Comment: That's a different question from your post. But sure, you can modify those parts in any number of ways.  Figure out exactly what you want to do, make the modifications, and ask questions if you run into problems.  There are a number of questions on SO with answers to similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Put the text between double quotes

```
"123-345-678-910
345-678-819-000"
```

and change the file extension to `.csv`.

Comment: Those files are actually generated from a query and are placed at a particular destination. They are to be picked up from my macro and place it in the corresponding cell. I cant edit those .txt files.

Comment: Then you're out of luck and need to merge the cells after importing the files into Excel.

Comment: But merging cells might give me unpredictable results right ?

Comment: That depends on your data and how you merge it.

Comment: Can i include in my macro whenever i import data from .txt files if it stretches to more than one cell..merge all those n cells into single cell. Is this feasible?

Comment: Why don't you just *try* it?

Comment: I'm new to VB and i just started using recording feature of macro. But i will try working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
txtfile = "Text File Path Here"
excelfile = "Excel File Path Here"
ExcelSheetName = "Sheet1"
ExcelRowToInsert = 1
ExcelColumnToInsert = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set tf = objFSO.OpenTextFile(txtfile, 1)

Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelfile)

Do Until tf.AtEndOfStream
    book.Sheets(ExcelSheetName).Cells(ExcelRowToInsert,ExcelColumnToInsert).Value = tf.ReadLine
    ExcelRowToInsert = ExcelRowToInsert + 1
Loop

tf.Close
book.Close True
objExcel.Quit
MsgBox "Task Completed", vbOKOnly, "Text to Excel"
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
Function ReadAllText(sFileName As String) As String 
    Dim iFileNumber As Integer
    iFileNumber = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As #iFileNumber
    ReadAllText = Input$(LOF(iFileNumber), iFileNumber)
    Close #iFileNumber
End Function

Sub Main()
    [A1] = Replace(ReadAllText("C:\Sample1.txt"), vbCr, "")
    [A2] = Replace(ReadAllText("C:\Sample2.txt"), vbCr, "")
End Sub
```